# Undefined property: stdClass::$comentarios laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un error a la hora de retornar una llave foranea en la vista, inicialmente en la ruta 'index' no hay ningun problema, ṕero al cambiar un poco la consulta y al cambiar la ruta, ya no sirve esta la vista index.

RUTAS

```
Route::get('/', 'SessionController@iniciarSession');
Route::get('/index', 'IndexController@index'); 
Route::get('/categoria/{nombre}', 'IndexController@cambiarCategoria');
Route::post('/temitas', 'TemaController@crearTema');
```

CONTROLADOR

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tema;
use App\Categoria;
class indexController extends Controller
{
 private $temas;
 private $categorias;

 public function index(Request $request){
  $usuario = $request->session()->get('login');
  if($usuario == null){
   return redirect('/');
  }
  $temas = Tema::all();
  $categorias = Categoria::all();
  return view('index',compact('temas','categorias'));
 }

 //es aqui donde tengo problemas

 public function cambiarCategoria($nombre){
  $categoria = DB::table('Categoria')
                  ->where('nombre',$nombre)
                  ->first();
  $categorias = Categoria::all();
  if($categoria== null){
   return abort(404);
  }else{
   $temas = DB::table('Tema')
              ->where('Categoria',$categoria->idCategoria)
              ->get();
   return view('index',compact('temas','categorias'));

  }
 }
}
```

VISTA

```
@foreach ($temas as $tema)
<a class="col-2 p-0 tema">
  <div class="capa"></div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <img src="storage/images/{{$tema->imagen}}" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    //aqui me da el error
    <span class="mr-1">{{count($tema->comentarios)}}</span>  <i class="fas  fa-comment"></i>                                  
  </div>
  <div class="titulo">
    {{$tema->titulo}}
  </div>
</a>
<p></p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: deberías mostrar el modelo tema y de comentario, aparentemente hay un problema en la relación, o no esta creada la relacion entre estos dos.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo dar fe de que la lógica de tus función opere correctamente pues no tenemos detalles de los modelos, pero el error se origina en la vista al hacer lo siguiente:

```
<...>{{ count($tema->comentarios) }}</...>
```

En esa sentencia estás intentando acceder a una propiedad de manera dinámica, tratando a `$tema` como objeto haciendo `$tema->comentarios`, algo que ya no es pues al retornar la vista hiciste uso de la función [Compact()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php):

```
return view('index',compact('temas','categorias'));
```

Lo que hace esa función -propia de PHP- es generar un arreglo/array asociativo de las variables que le envíes.

Es por eso que el error que te arroja es el siguiente:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$comentarios laravel

Pues esa propiedad no existe ahí.

### Solución

En tu vista, en lugar de:

```
<...>{{ count($tema->comentarios) }}</...>
```

podrías hacer acceder a las propiedades como si fuera un arreglo:

```
<...>{{ count($tema['comentarios']) }}</...>
```